# Cutter cannot parse AUTDA instruction

Tags: arm, rizin, cutter

I work on reverse engineering of an iOS software using Cutter, and receive several opcodes as "invalid". For example:

```
<addr>      301ac1da               invalid
```

Looking up the hex code, I found out this is the [AUTDA](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2020-12/Base-Instructions/AUTDA--AUTDZA--Authenticate-Data-address--using-key-A-) instruction. Seems like for some reason Cutter / rizin cannot parse this kind of instructions.

I tried to write `pd` in the console directly, but it gave the same results.
Version info:

```
Version 2.1.2
Using rizin 0.4.1 (9023f8b)
Based on Qt 5.15.5 (Clang 13.0 (Apple), 64 bit)
Optional Features:
Python: ON
Python Bindings: ON
```

Is there a way to make Cutter recognize this instruction?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible in the near future once the Capstone "auto-sync" project is complete, and Rizin/Cutter updated used Capstone library. The brief description of the "auto-sync" is that it regenerates disassemblers, in this particular case for ARM, from the LLVM TableGen representations, semi-automatically: https://github.com/capstone-engine/capstone/issues/2015

You can track the progress once this PR will be merged in Rizin: https://github.com/rizinorg/rizin/pull/3564